# The right way to clear out the obstacle on costmap?

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I confronted a problem. In my application, I need to reset the pose of the robot now and then (by publish to the /initialpose for amcl), however, after I have reset the robot pose, the previous obstacles around the robot are still there on the costmap (global costmap and/or local?) which always resulted in no valid path found by the navfn global planner. I am asking what is the right way to clear out the obstacles on the costmap after I reset the pose of the robot? I am now using fuete.

Thank you everyone!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173134/the-right-way-to-clear-out-the-obstacle-on-costmap?/) by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the /move_base/clear_costmaps service.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-06-09**:
Thanks dornhege

**Comment by [Dharmateja Kadem](https://answers.ros.org/users/26024/dharmateja-kadem/) on 2016-06-09**:
will clear_costmaps service clears both static and dynamic obstacles or only dynamic obstacles (which are not there in the map) ?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-10-21**:
@Dharmateja Kadem, you must configure the layers you want to clean, so it depends what layers you have  and how you populated them. if you want more details, please ask a new question.